# Web scraping returns empty

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

My first attempt at learning scraping. I am trying to get the official names of members of the U.S. Congress.

I successfully did a POST -- `response.content` is indeed the full html string. But somehow `lxml` and `bs4` aren't helping me get the name out.

Here's a short example, searching for last name "Waxman" on [this site](http://bioguide.congress.gov/biosearch/biosearch.asp). The result I want is the person's full name, as stated in the table. I did Inspect Element > copy XPATH on the name.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

shortname = 'WAXMAN'
state = 'California'
chamber = 'House'

url = 'http://bioguide.congress.gov/biosearch/biosearch1.asp'
formData = {'lastname': shortname}

response = requests.post(url, data=formData)
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
print tree.xpath('/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a/text()')
```

My attempt in beautifulSoup doesn't work either, but I'm less familiar with that package.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
soup.select('body > center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > a')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your expression to simply:

```
//table//td/a/text()
```

Results into `['WAXMAN, Henry Arnold']` being printed.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. Can you give any hint about why mine failed?

Comment: @Hatshepsut well, first of all the `tbody` is something usually inserted by the browser. Print out the `response.content` and see what the HTML got by `requests` actually is. Don't assume it would be the same as in the browser.